# Gradient of random forest loss in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, random-forest

I'm trying to create some adversarial examples for random forest by adding some noise to test images and checking whether they fool the model. I'm running into error when trying to find the gradient of loss function (which I defined as a cross entropy function) as shown below. I've pasted the error message below. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

```
# Import MNIST data
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=False)
mnist1 = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

# Parameters
num_steps = 500 # Total steps to train
batch_size = 1024 # The number of samples per batch
num_classes = 10 # The 10 digits
num_features = 784 # Each image is 28x28 pixels
num_trees = 10
max_nodes = 1000

tf.reset_default_graph()
# Input and Target data
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, num_features])
# For random forest, labels must be integers (the class id)
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=[None])
Y1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10]) # 0-9 digits recognition => 10 classes


# Random Forest Parameters
hparams = tensor_forest.ForestHParams(num_classes=num_classes,
                                      num_features=num_features,
                                      num_trees=num_trees,
                                      max_nodes=max_nodes).fill()

# Build the Random Forest
forest_graph = tensor_forest.RandomForestGraphs(hparams)
# Get training graph and loss
train_op = forest_graph.training_graph(X, Y)
loss_op = forest_graph.training_loss(X, Y)

# Measure the accuracy
infer_op, _, _ = forest_graph.inference_graph(X)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(infer_op, 1), tf.cast(Y, tf.int64))
accuracy_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
y_pred = tf.argmax(infer_op, 1)
y_pred1 = tf.nn.softmax(infer_op)


# Minimize error using cross entropy
loss = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(Y1*tf.log(y_pred1)))
# loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square( tf.cast(y_pred, tf.float64) - Y))
grad_input = tf.gradients(loss, X)[0]

# Initialize the variables (i.e. assign their default value) and forest resources
init_vars = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
    resources.initialize_resources(resources.shared_resources()))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_vars)
    #Training
    for i in range(1, num_steps + 1):
        # Prepare Data
        # Get the next batch of MNIST data (only images are needed, not labels)
        batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
        _, l = sess.run([train_op, loss_op], feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y: batch_y})
        if i % 50 == 0 or i == 1:
            acc = sess.run(accuracy_op, feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y: batch_y})
            print('Step %i, Loss: %f, Acc: %f' % (i, l, acc))

    # Test Model
    test_x, test_y = mnist.test.images, mnist.test.labels
    print("Test Accuracy:", sess.run(accuracy_op, feed_dict={X: test_x, Y: test_y}))
#     infer,correct_pred = sess.run([infer_op,correct_prediction], feed_dict={X:  mnist.train.images, Y:  mnist.train.labels})
    #prediction for one image
    y_prediction = sess.run(y_pred, feed_dict={X:  mnist.test.images[12:13],Y:  mnist.test.labels[12:13]})

    #adversial 
    grad = sess.run([grad_input], feed_dict={X:mnist.test.images, Y1:mnist1.test.labels})
```

The error message is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-3fd00c3b2207> in <module>()
     22 
     23     #adversial
---> 24     grad = sess.run([grad_input], feed_dict={X:mnist.test.images, Y1:mnist1.test.labels})
     25 #     grad = np.array(grad)
     26 #     grad = grad.reshape(10000,784)

/home/black-book/anaconda3/envs/py2tensor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    898     try:
    899       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 900                          run_metadata_ptr)
    901       if run_metadata:
    902         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/home/black-book/anaconda3/envs/py2tensor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1118     # Create a fetch handler to take care of the structure of fetches.
   1119     fetch_handler = _FetchHandler(
-> 1120         self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_tensor, feed_handles=feed_handles)
   1121 
   1122     # Run request and get response.

/home/black-book/anaconda3/envs/py2tensor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in __init__(self, graph, fetches, feeds, feed_handles)
    425     """
    426     with graph.as_default():
--> 427       self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
    428     self._fetches = []
    429     self._targets = []

/home/black-book/anaconda3/envs/py2tensor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in for_fetch(fetch)
    243     elif isinstance(fetch, (list, tuple)):
    244       # NOTE(touts): This is also the code path for namedtuples.
--> 245       return _ListFetchMapper(fetch)
    246     elif isinstance(fetch, dict):
    247       return _DictFetchMapper(fetch)

/home/black-book/anaconda3/envs/py2tensor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in __init__(self, fetches)
    350     """
    351     self._fetch_type = type(fetches)
--> 352     self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
    353     self._unique_fetches, self._value_indices = _uniquify_fetches(self._mappers)
    354 

/home/black-book/anaconda3/envs/py2tensor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in for_fetch(fetch)
    240     if fetch is None:
    241       raise TypeError('Fetch argument %r has invalid type %r' % (fetch,
--> 242                                                                  type(fetch)))
    243     elif isinstance(fetch, (list, tuple)):
    244       # NOTE(touts): This is also the code path for namedtuples.

TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <type 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: The `grad_input` tensor is `None`. Check if `X` is actually linked to the subgraph computing the loss

Comment: @GiuseppeMarra Yes, I've checked the X and it is linked to the subgraph. I made a few changes and now I'm getting a new error. The change is  `infer_opp = sess.run([infer_op], feed_dict={X:mnist.test.images})
    infer_opp = np.reshape(infer_opp, (10000,10))
    y_test_pred = sess.run([y_pred1], feed_dict={infer_op: infer_opp})
    print (y_test_pred[0])
    grad = sess.run([grad_input], feed_dict={y_pred1:y_test_pred, Y1:mnist1.test.labels})` and the error is `Cannot feed value of shape (1, 10000, 10) for Tensor u'Softmax:0', which has shape '(?, ?)'` indicating the last line of the code!